# Choosing a model function for optimization

Tags: optimization, curve-fitting

When finding a curve fitting of some data like this, which formula is good to choose?

Is this a good one?

y = c0 + ln(c1*x)

[image]

```
x
55.5
55.5
55.5
55.5
55.5
56.0
58.0
60.0
63.5
67.5
72.5
77.5
83.0
88.0
92.5
98.5
105.0
112.5
119.5
126.5
133.5
141.5
150.0
157.5
165.5
175.0
183.5
190.0
197.5
204.5
212.5
219.0
225.5
232.0
239.0
245.5
251.0
258.0
265.0
272.5
278.5
284.5
289.0
292.5
295.0
296.5
297.0
297.5
299.5
```

```
y
42.5
45.0 
48.5
53.0
58.0
63.5
70.0
75.5
81.5
87.5
93.5
99.5
105.0
110.0
115.5
121.0
126.5
132.0
138.5
144.0
149.5
155.0
160.5
165.5
170.5
175.5
179.5
183.0
187.0
190.0
193.0
196.0
198.5
201.0
203.5
205.5
207.5
209.5
212.0
213.5
214.5
215.5
216.0
216.5
216.5
216.5
216.5
216.5
216.5
```

Comment: Instead of a graph could you post the data ?

Comment: Here is the data. 
[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fdj8n7XluBWzOkdLEyWk1pkQOiqW0k7n/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Thank you for the link. But I will not use it because I don't want create a compte as it is asked for. Please post the data on an open site where no condition is required for access.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What is your data?

Comment: @JJacquelin
Thank you for your comment. I added the data on my post.

Comment: Model choice should be determined and driven by what you are modeling as described by Infinity77. Additionally for your proposed model note that it is equivalent to `c0 + log(c1*x) = c0 + log(c1) + log(x) = c* + log(x)` a one parameter model with a fixed coefficient on `log(x)` (pretty restrictive model. It could be feasible if thats what the science behind the data says it should be, but I doubt it. )

Comment: @grape100 when the users here are asking what your data is they did not necessarily mean they want to see the actual values, but they want to know what they represent (what is x? what is y?) are they bounded? continuous?

Comment: @bdenovic Thank you for your comment. It makes things more clear to me. 
The data is a handwritten path. An xy coordinate represents a location on a smartphone screen and I think it's continuous.

Comment: I do not think it is appropriate to model one coordinate based on the other in such data, that makes no sense. What is the purpose of your analysis? That will help identify the appropriate statistical framework to use.

Comment: I'm trying to make an optimizer or excel solver from scratch with zero knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t think you should actually “choose” a curve fitting function. What do your data points represent? If they are the outcome of something real, then you might want to try and think of a model of that “something”. The moment you have a model, you’ll have your fitting function.